# How to infer a DateTime from a quarter string?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dateframe column `Time Period`. In the column I have mixed time periods, with a unique list as follows, with the time initially recorded as quarterly and then switching to monthly.

```
Time Period
2018 Q1
2018 Q2
2018 Jul
2018 Aug
2018 Sep
2018 Oct
2018 Nov
2018 Dec
```

I am attempting to set the above `to_datetime` using the Pandas to_datetime function.

Code
 `year_data['Time Period'] = pd.to_datetime(year_data['Time Period'])`

However, `2018 Q1` and  `2018 Q2` are producing the following error - `valueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2018 Q1')`

What I was hoping to achuieve is the following.

```
Time Period
01/03/2018
01/06/2018
01/07/2018
01/08/2018
01/09/2018
01/10/2018
01/11/2018
01/12/2018
```

Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periods are by default parsing by first month, only necessary replace empty string to `-`:

```
year_data['Time Period'] = pd.to_datetime(year_data['Time Period'].str.replace(' ', '-'))
print (year_data)
  Time Period
0  2018-01-01
1  2018-04-01
2  2018-07-01
3  2018-08-01
4  2018-09-01
5  2018-10-01
6  2018-11-01
7  2018-12-01
```

But is possible add `2` months for values parsed from quarters:

```
m = year_data['Time Period'].str.contains('Q')
year_data['Time Period'] = pd.to_datetime(year_data['Time Period'].str.replace(' ', '-'))

year_data.loc[m, 'Time Period'] += pd.DateOffset(months=2)
```

Last for custom format in strings `DD/MM/YYYY` use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
year_data['Time Period'] = year_data['Time Period'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print (year_data)
  Time Period
0  01/03/2018
1  01/06/2018
2  01/07/2018
3  01/08/2018
4  01/09/2018
5  01/10/2018
6  01/11/2018
7  01/12/2018
```

Comment: Nice solution, but OP wants `2018 Q1` to be `2018/03`.